# Does anyone have a proof that the intersection and union of two compact sets is compact.

Tags: calculus, analysis, compactness

I have my take on it. It is quite informal and don;t know where it would be evaluated correctly on an exam. Since the sets are compact that means for every open cover there is a finite cover.

When the intersection is in question, taking any two covers of the sets, then there respective finite covers and taking that intersection of two finite covers gives us a finite cover of an intersection.

For union just taking the finite covers and uniting them also gives us a finite cover of a union. Would this be sufficient in your opinions?

Comment: Big problem: Without Hausdorffness, the intersection of two (quasi)compact sets need not be (quasi)compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For union you are right.

(For Hausdorff spaces only)
For intersection you can think in this way too take any open cover  of $A\cap B$ then extend it to an open cover of $A$ or $B$, say $A$ [by taking $x\in A-B$ and choose a fixed $z\in A\cap B$ then $\forall x\in A-B$ take open sets $U_x$ now take their union, then $A$ has finite subcover and that corresponding subcover will also be the subcover of $A\cap B$.

Comment: How should one extend the open cover of $A\cap B$ to an open cover of $A$ (or $B$)?

Comment: Conceivably novices to point-set topology could miss @DanielFischer's point: without Hausdorff-ness, compact sets need not be closed! Such stuff! But, yes, with Hausdorff-ness this (possibly counter-intuitive, but relevant to algebraic geometry, at least) issue is skirted.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I have no experience in topology, so sorry for any silly questions ahead. If $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $A\cap B$, isn't $\mathcal U \cup \{ A \}$ an open cover of $A$?

Comment: Yes but then the subcover of $U \cup \{A\}$ will be $A$ itself which is not a subcover of $U$.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel Fischer hausdorffness will be required.

Comment: @user152715 I see. Thanks

Comment: In a Hausdorff space, compact sets are closed; so $A\cap B$ is a closed subset of $A$ and hence it is compact: no need to use covers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used calculus as a tag, I will assume for this question that you are using the Euclidean Space, that is, any subet of $\mathbb R^n$.

I will provide you with a proof for the union.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Since $A$ and $B$ are compact, we know from Heine-Borel Theorem that they are closed and bounded, that is $\exists M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $a \le M_1$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \le M_2$ for all $b \in B$. Now, choose $M^*= \max\{M_1, M_2\}$ then we clearly have that $x \le M^*$ for every $x \in A \cup B$. Thus $A\cup B$ is bounded.
>
> We must now show that $A \cup B$ is closed and then we are done. Notice, however, that $A \cup B$ is the union of a finite number of closed sets and must thus be closed.
>
> We thus have that $A \cup B$ is compact in $\mathbb R^n$, since it is both closed and bounded in $\mathbb R^n$.